# How to run a function Asynchronously in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I have Spring App. It is using moduleApplicationContext.xml for configuring the Beans. I want to run an Asynchronous function in my Controller and it should not wait for the response to send.

After googling, I came to know about @Async Annotation.

Then I have performed the following Steps for adding Async Service;

#### 1. I have enabled the Async Operation in moduleApplicationContext.xml file

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" exception-handler="exceptionHandler"/>
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="7-42" queue-capacity="8"/>
```

#### 2. I have created a file for Handling the Exceptions for Asynchronous Operations

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler;

public class CustomAsyncExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable throwable, Method method, Object... obj) {

        System.out.println("Exception message - " + throwable.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Method name - " + method.getName());
        for (Object param : obj) {
            System.out.println("Parameter value - " + param);
        }
    }

}
```

I have added its bean in moduleApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="exceptionHandler" class="org.raxa.module.raxacore.util.CustomAsyncExceptionHandler"/>
```

#### 3. I have added an Async Method in my Service and ServiceImpl

```
@Async("myExecutor")
    public void asynchronousFunction() throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("Asynchronous Operation Starts");
        Thread.sleep(1000L); //Intentional delay
        log.info("Asynchronous Operation Ends");
    }
```

Now I am calling an Asynchronous Function in my Controller Class for a particular End-Point '/temp'.

```
Context.getService(RaxaCdsService.class).asynchronousFunction();
```

However, I am getting the Following Error in my Tomcat logs

```
ERROR - FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(497) |2019-03-18 12:00:47,642| Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getInternalParentBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1107)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.openmrs.web.DispatcherServlet.init(DispatcherServlet.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If there is some configuration issue in my Existing Application for @Async Annotation to work please let me know. I would be good if the solution is Xml Configuration Based as I am using it.
 Or If there is another better way of performing some async operation after the rest call response is Send please let me know.

Comment: Try this <task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="7-42" queue-capacity="8"/>
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" exception-handler="exceptionHandler"/>

Comment: My order of Enabling Async is based on this doc 
[Spring Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html)  . I try your suggestion and see.

Comment: @Araf it is not working